# JAVA - Output in mixed order?

Tags: java, string, printing, output

I'm writing a very the basic program where I put in a string and it prints the word, and the first and last letter of the string. The output should be seen as follows:

word :: Hello

first letter :: H

last letter :: o

However, this is not the case. The letters appear before the word, and well, basically the orders and spacing is crazy! Hopefully someone can help me. Here is the code:

FirstAndLast Class:

```js
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class FirstAndLast
{
 private String word;

 public FirstAndLast(String s)
 {
     word = s;
 }

 public void setString(String s)
 {
     word = s;
 }
 
 public String getWord ()
 {
      out.print(word);
      return "";
 }
 
 public String getFirst()
 {
  out.print(word.charAt(0));
     return "";
 }
 
 public String getLast()
 {
     out.print(word.charAt((word.length())-1));
     return "";
 }

  public String toString()
  {
      String output="";
   return output;
 }
}
```

The Runner Class:

```js
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class FirstRunner
{
 public static void main ( String[] args )
 {
  FirstAndLast demo = new FirstAndLast("Hello");
  System.out.println( "Word :: " + demo.getWord() );
  System.out.println( "First letter :: " + demo.getFirst() );
  System.out.println( "Last letter :: " + demo.getLast() );
  
  FirstAndLast bri = new FirstAndLast("Brianna");
  System.out.println( "Word :: " + bri.getWord() );
  System.out.println( "First letter :: " + bri.getFirst() );
  System.out.println( "Last letter :: " + bri.getLast() );
  
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript has NOTHING to do with Java.

Comment: `System.out.println( "First letter :: " + demo.getFirst() );` <- this means: call `demo.getFirst()`, then print "First letter :: " followed by whatever it returned. The program did exactly what you told it to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class FirstAndLast
{
    private String word;

    public FirstAndLast(String s)
    {
        word = s;
    }

    public String getWord ()
    {
         return word;
    }

    public char getFirst()
    {
        return word.charAt(0);
    }

    public char getLast()
    {
        return word.charAt((word.length())-1);
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were returning `""`, or nothing, for the `getWord()`, `getLast()`, and `getFirst()` methods. Instead you could return what you want to print.

Comment: Thanks, but now its saying char cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: try converting the type of the method